# Infinite product with sign changes.

Tags: infinite-product

For infinite products I know the following theorems:

Theorem I. If $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n$ then $\prod (1+a_n)$ converges if and only if $\sum a_n$ converges.

Theorem II. If $-1 < a_n \leq 0$ for all $n$ then $\prod (1+a_n)$ converges if and only if $\sum a_n$ converges.

My question is what are necessary and sufficient conditions (possibly including more restrictions than in I and II) for $\prod (1+a_n)$ convergence/divergence as related to  $\sum a_n$ convergence/divergence  if the sequence of terms $a_n$ can switch signs repeatedly but always stay greater than $-1$.

I already know the trivial equivalence of $\prod(1+a_n)$ and $\sum\ln(1+a_n)$.

Comment: You asked the same question more than a year ago https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2966559/convergence-of-infinite-product-prod1a-n-where-a-n-changes-sign

Comment: @pigeon: Thanks for pointing that out. The answer there gives a sufficient condition when $\sum a_n^2$ converges but I am now hoping to see something more general including necessary conditions. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example to consider.
$$
a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\;.
$$
[Note, for $n \ge 2$, we have $-1 < a_n < 1$ so $0 < 1+a_n < 2$.]

Then of course the alternating series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n$ converges.  But
what about infinite product
$$
\prod_{n=2}^\infty\big(1+a_n\big)=\prod_{n=2}^\infty\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\;?
$$
We have as $n \to \infty$:
$$
\log\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right) = 
\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{2n} + O(n^{-3/2})\;.
$$
Thus,
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\log\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)
$$
is the sum of a series $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$that converges, a series $-\sum\frac{1}{2n}$ that diverges to $-\infty$, and a series that converges by limit comparison with $\sum n^{-3/2}$.

Therefore
$$
\prod_{n=2}^\infty\big(1+a_n\big)
$$
diverges to $0$.

---

The reciprocal series
$$
\prod_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{1+a_n}= \prod_{n=2}^\infty\big({1+b_n}\big)
$$
diverges to $+\infty$ while the series $\sum b_n$ still converges.  And $-1 <b_n< 1$ for $n \ge 4$.

Comment: Thank you.  I can see now that there is no simple set conditions, but this definitely clears up some things for me.